# Where has the "Preview" gone when editing posts?

Tags: bug, edits, suggested-edits

As of today, I can no longer see the "preview" when editing a post. This is true **both** for posts I am editing whilst in the "Suggested Edits" review queue **and** for posts I am editing 'organically' (i.e. directly from that post's page).

Is this bug related to the recent adoption of "Highlight.js?"

It *may* be specific to Stack Overflow (in which case, just let me know and I'll repost on Meta.SO); also, I notice that I *can* see a preview while I am typing this question. (EDIT: And I can also see it while I am editing this post, after having previously posted it.)

*I have now identified this being related to running the "Stack Exchange CV Request Generator" user-script. So, I guess it's specific to Stack Overflow - but maybe connected (indirectly) to the change to highlight.js?*

Answer (score 5):

Below the edit box, there's an option 'Hide preview':

[image]

Did you touch that by accident? This setting is stored per site, so that explains why you're having the problem on Stack Overflow but not here.

Comment: I can see the "hide preview" and it changes to "show preview" when I click - but nothing actually changes. But see the edit to my question: It's clearly one of the userscripts causing it ... I'll get back when I have identified which one.

Comment: Ah right, thanks for the update. Still, other users might have a similar problem as you exactly because of the reason I described, so I'm leaving this answer up.

Comment: Well - with 3 up and (only) 1 down so far, I'm happy to leave the question. I could do with wee boost to my Meta-Rep. :-)